# Merge 2 files then concatenate columns

Tags: shell, csv, join, awk, concatenation

I'm working on sort, join and awk 2 csv files (semi-colon separator) that are associated by the first column.

**File1.csv:**

```
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_11  
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_12  
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_13  
TL_02;labelSD3;PFL_04  
TL_03;labelSD4;PFL_05
```

**File2.csv:**

```
TL_01;labelRT1;JV_111  
TL_02;labelRT3;JV_02  
TL_03;labelRT4;JV_03
```

I want to merge those two files and concatenate the multiple values of the third column in `File1.csv` in one colums with '#' separator following this model:

**RightMerge.csv:**

```
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_11#PFL_12#PFL_13;labelRT1;JV_111  
TL_02;labelSD3;PFL_04;labelRT3;JV_02  
TL_03;labelSD4;PFL_05;labelRT4;JV_03
```

Actually, I am able to merge the 2 files but not to concatenate multiples values with a specific character (#) with the following command (files are already sorted by the first column):

```
join -11 -21 File1.csv File2.csv -t ';' > FileOut.csv
```

Which gives the following result:

**FileOut.csv:**

```
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_11;labelRT1;JV_111  
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_12;labelRT1;JV_111  
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_13;labelRT1;JV_111  
TL_02;labelSD3;PFL_04;labelRT3;JV_02  
TL_03;labelSD4;PFL_05;labelRT4;JV_03
```

After this, I am trying to use `awk` script to concat the first 3 lines like this:

```
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_11#PFL_12#PFL_13;labelRT1;JV_111
```

But I didn't find a solution to this.
Should I continue with the awk treatment or there is another way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
NR==FNR { key2val[$1] = ($1 in key2val ? key2val[$1] "#" $3 : $0); next }
{ print key2val[$1], $2, $3 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
TL_01;labelSD1;PFL_11#PFL_12#PFL_13;labelRT1;JV_111
TL_02;labelSD3;PFL_04;labelRT3;JV_02
TL_03;labelSD4;PFL_05;labelRT4;JV_03
```

It only assumes your posted sample input data is truly representative of your real data, e.g. every key value is present in both files, etc. If that's not the case then edit your question to show some more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: Yes every key value is present in both files.

Comment: Could you explain a bit the following line:
key2val[$1] = ($1 in key2val ? key2val[$1] "#" $3 : $0); next

I'm not sure to understand  every operations.

Comment: It's just a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) `variable = (condition ? value if true : value if false)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one also,

```
cat FileOut.csv | 
       awk '
       BEGIN{
             FS=OFS=SUBSEP=";"
       }
       NF>1{
             a[$1,$2,$4,$5] = a[$1,$2,$4,$5]";"$3
       }
       END{
             for(i in a){
                  split(i,arr,";");
                  print arr[1]";"arr[2]";"a[i]";"arr[3]";"arr[4]
                  }
       }' | 
sort
```

Check it

Comment: This work for the concatenation but the order of the column isn't right. It could be modified eaysily. The separator caracter of the concatenation is not defined.